# Typscript: How do I Call Nested Array on Vue Data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I created an interface with the code below:

```
export interface ISubcategories {
    subCategoryTopic: string;
    subCategoryImageURL: string;
    subCategoryImage: ISubcategoryImages[];
}

export interface ISubcategoryImages {
    podcastImageURL: string;
    videoImageURL: string;
    articleImageURL: string;
}

export interface ICategories {
    categoryTopic: string;
    subCategory: ISubcategories[];
}
```

I called it in the data section of my vuejs code with:

```
categoryData: {
  categoryTopic: "" as string,
  subCategory: [] as Array<ISubcategories>,
},
```

However, when I do add the code below to the textbox where I want the data to be, I get this error **:**

> _vm.categoryData.subCategory.subCategoryImage is undefined.

What should I do ?

```
v-model="categoryData.subCategory.subCategoryImage.podcastImageURL"
```

Comment: Since subCategory is an array and arrays don't have the property `subCategoryImage` this won't work. I think that what you should do is to access a given index in `subCategory` something like: `categoryData.subCategory[0].subCategoryImage[0].podcastImageURL` the smae with `subCategoryImage` both properties are arrays so you have to access them with and index.

Answer (score 0):

One observation **:** As `subCategory` & `subCategoryImage` in interface `ISubcategories` is defined as an array. You can not access it's object directly with `dot(.)` notation. You can access elements via index or by iteration.

**For ex :**

```
<div v-for="(subCat, index) in categoryData.subCategory" :key="index">
    <div v-for"(imageUrl, i) in subCat.subCategoryImage" :key="i">
        <input v-model="imageUrl.podcastImageURL"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works if I am retrieving from the database, but I am passing the data from the form to the database. Thank you for the code

Comment: That's fine. I just show you how it will work. It's not about the source of data but it's about how you will access the particular property from an nested array of object.